# Separating the Rails app from the database using 2 different servers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, scaling, system-administration

Separating the database from the actual Rails app is probably the first thing everyone will do when they want to scale their app, but still, I'm unable to find a tutorial on how to do it. Can someone give me a link to a page or a chapter in a book that explains how to deal with this problem?

Thanks.

PS: I'll probably use Nginx as an web server, PostgreSQL as RDBMS so it's better if the tutorial will use them as an example.

Answer (score 4):

1. Set up the application servers as usual but without installing a database.
2. Set up the database server and ensure application servers are able to connect.
3. Specify the database server and credentials in `config/database.yml`

That's mostly it.

Comment: Ok, but how does the app know where to look? I don't see any attribute  in the config/database.yml that specifies the ip address.

Comment: The setting is `host` in the specific environment in `config/database.yml`.